# How do I explicitly call a method on a slice without using a typedef?

Tags: rust

I want to call a method that is implemented for the type `&[i32]`. I can do it via type alias as shown on line marked **1**, but is it possible without introducing a type alias every time?

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn say_hi(x: T);
}

impl<'a> Foo<i32> for &'a [i32] {
    fn say_hi(x: i32) {}
}

type Array<'a> = &'a [i32];

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3];
    Array::say_hi(1);//line 1
    &[i32]::say_hi(1);//line 2
}
```

The line marked **2** produces an error message:

```
error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `::`
  --> /home/xxx/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-08-09-051114/snippet.rs:21:11
   |
21 |     &[i32]::say_hi(1);
   |           ^^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator here

error[E0423]: expected value, found builtin type `i32`
  --> /home/xxx/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-08-09-051114/snippet.rs:21:7
   |
21 |     &[i32]::say_hi(1);
   |       ^^^ not a value
```

Is it possible to modify the line marked **2** to not have a compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Fully Qualified Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name):

```rust
<&[i32]>::say_hi(1);
```

---

This is **not** a method, by the way. A method takes `self` in some form. This is just an *associated function*. If it *was* a method, you could just call it like any other method:

```rust
trait Foo<T> {
    fn say_hi(&self, x: T);
}

impl Foo<i32> for [i32] {
    fn say_hi(&self, x: i32) {}
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3];
    <[i32]>::say_hi(&arr, 1);
    arr.say_hi(1);
}
```