# How to use serde's skip_serializing_if with empty slices?

Tags: rust, serde

One can do `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Vec::is_empty")]` for `Vec`s, but what is the equivalent for slices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I explicitly call a method on a slice without using a typedef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580658/how-do-i-explicitly-call-a-method-on-a-slice-without-using-a-typedef)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slice type `[T]` has an [`is_empty`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_empty) method too. Here is how you would call it:

```
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct S<'a> {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "<[_]>::is_empty")]
    slice: &'a [String]
}

fn main() {
    let s = S { slice: &[] };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap());
}
```